# Заполнить массив значениями из БД для вывода в зависимый выпадающий список PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, заполнить массив `$city` значениями из БД для вывода в зависимый выпадающий список. Пытался сделать, но выводит только последнее проработанное значение из цикла, и понятия не имею как на PHP заставить это работать..
Запрос к БД:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT pupils.classes_cID, pupils.pID, pupils.name, 
                     pupils.middle_name, pupils.surname, classes.cID, classes.cName from pupils,classes
                     WHERE pupils.classes_cID=classes.cID");
```

Заполнение:

```
$n=mysql_num_rows($result);
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
    $city = array (
      mysql_result($result,$i,'classes.cname') => array (
        $i => mysql_result($result,$i,'pupils.name').' '.
              mysql_result($result,$i,'pupils.middle_name').' '.
              mysql_result($result,$i,'pupils.surname')
      )
    );
}
```

Пытался сделать по вот такому примеру:

```
    <?php // файл city.php
$city = array (
  'Москва и Московская обл.' => array (
    0 => 'Москва',
    1 => 'Абрамцево',
    // ...
  ),
  'Санкт-Петербург и область' => array (
    0 => 'Санкт-Петербург',
    1 => 'Александровская',
    // ...
  ),
  // ...
);
?>
```

Comment: покажите данные которые получаете из базы

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f5fma4 как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

На третьей строке вы каждый проход цикла присваивате значение переменной *$city* новое значение. Для того, что бы массив наполнялся значениями нужно добавлять в уже существующий массив, значения.

```
$n = mysql_num_rows($result);

$cities = []; // Объявляем пустой массив, который будет хранить все записи.

for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $cities[] = array( // Пополняем массив значениями.
        mysql_result($result, $i, 'classes.cname') => array(
            $i => mysql_result($result, $i, 'pupils.name') . ' ' .
                mysql_result($result, $i, 'pupils.middle_name') . ' ' .
                mysql_result($result, $i, 'pupils.surname')
        )
    );
}
```